# HidDevice.FromIdAsync() cannot open device in FileAccessMode::ReadWrite mode in Win32 app

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-runtime, hid, c++-winrt

I trying to use [Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.devices.humaninterfacedevice) UWP API to open HID device (gamepad in my case) and send HID output report. But `HidDevice.FromIdAsync()` method cannot open device in `FileAccessMode::ReadWrite` mode in my classic console Win32 app:

[image]

Here is minimal C++/WinRT repro example:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"

#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Devices.Enumeration.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.h>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Devices::Enumeration;
using namespace Windows::Devices::HumanInterfaceDevice;
using namespace Windows::Storage;

void OnDeviceAdded(const winrt::Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation& deviceInformation)
{
    std::cout << "*****Device Init End*******" << std::endl;

    try {
        string id = to_string(deviceInformation.Id());
        string name = to_string(deviceInformation.Name());

        std::cout << "New HID device connected:" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Id: " << id << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Name: " << name << std::endl;

        HidDevice m_Device = HidDevice::FromIdAsync(deviceInformation.Id(), FileAccessMode::ReadWrite).get();

        if (!m_Device)
        {
            std::cout << "Cannot open device for writing! Trying read-only..." << std::endl;
            m_Device = HidDevice::FromIdAsync(deviceInformation.Id(), FileAccessMode::Read).get();
        }

        if (!m_Device)
        {
            std::cout << "Cannot open device for reading!" << std::endl;
            throw;
        }

        uint16_t vendorId = m_Device.VendorId();
        uint16_t productId = m_Device.ProductId();
        uint16_t version = m_Device.Version();
        uint16_t usagePage = m_Device.UsagePage();
        uint16_t usageId = m_Device.UsageId();

        std::cout << "VendorId: " << vendorId << std::endl;
        std::cout << "ProductId: " << productId << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Version: " << version << std::endl;
        std::cout << "UsagePage: " << usagePage << std::endl;
        std::cout << "UsageId: " << usageId << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "Something went wrong while device init! :(" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "*****Device Init End*******" << std::endl;
}

hstring hidDeviceSelector;
DeviceWatcher hidDeviceWatcher = nullptr;
event_token hidAddedToken;

int main()
{
    winrt::init_apartment();

    hidDeviceSelector = HidDevice::GetDeviceSelector(0x01 /*HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC*/, 0x05 /*HID_USAGE_GENERIC_GAMEPAD*/);
    hidDeviceWatcher = DeviceInformation::CreateWatcher(hidDeviceSelector);
    hidAddedToken = hidDeviceWatcher.Added(std::bind(&OnDeviceAdded, std::placeholders::_2));
    hidDeviceWatcher.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        // wait
    }

    hidDeviceWatcher.Added(hidAddedToken);

    winrt::uninit_apartment();

    return 0;
}
```

Similar questions regarding UWP apps mentioning that there should be `*.appxmanifest` like this:

```xml
 <Capabilities>
    <DeviceCapability Name="humaninterfacedevice">
      <!--SuperMutt Device-->
      <Device Id="vidpid:045E 0610">
        <Function Type="usage:FFAA 0001" />
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
  </Capabilities>
```

But seems this is only needed for UWP apps.

It worth to mention that [HidDevice Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.devices.humaninterfacedevice.hiddevice) have [DualApiPartition attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/apiindex/uwp-apis-callable-from-a-classic-desktop-app) and API should be allowed to be called from any desktop app.

This is bug or I'm missing something?

My C++/WinRT demo app code is here:
https://github.com/DJm00n/HidGamepadConsoleApp

Comment: Have you verified that the devices in question can actually be written to? Performing a write operation to an input device (like a gamepad) reads odd. As an aside, you can drop the `to_string` conversions and write the properties to `std::wcout` using the [c_str](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/hstring#hstringc_str-function) member.

Comment: I need write access to device to send HID output report with vibration later (via HidDevice.SendOutputReportAsync()). These devices supports vibration via HID API. 
See https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/device/gamepad/dualshock4_controller.cc#L226 for example.